# British Citizen with Canadian mother, needing passport

Tags: canada, citizenship, passport, dual-citizenship, uk-citizenship

On a recent trip to Canada, I applied for my ETA as I am a British Citizen. It got denied as I was recognised as a Canadian citizen as my mother was born in Canada and always maintained full Canadian citizenship. I had to get an emergency electronic Canadian passport attached to my UK passport for the duration of the holiday. I am now looking to apply for my Canadian passport, how do I go about this? Do I need to obtain a certificate of Canadian citizenship first?

Comment: Isn't this the happiest visa denial ever?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, assuming you were not born in Canada, you need to apply for and get a Certificate of Canadian Citizenship first before you can apply for a Canadian passport. Proving that your mother was born in Canada should be enough to prove that you are currently a Canadian citizen.

Comment: Thanks. When I applied for my ETA and got rejected, it was stated in the email that it was on the grounds that I am already recognised as a citizen. Any ideas how I go about applying?

Comment: @MarekWeir: [Here](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/application-citizenship-certificate-adults-minors.html) is the application

Comment: Merci, much appreciated

Comment: If someone is "already recognized as a citizen," why is it necessary to have a Certificate of Canadian Citizenship before applying for a passport?

Comment: @phoog: I'm not sure what "already recognized as a citizen" means. He doesn't have a certificate, and so does not have any official documentation of his citizenship. However, the fact that his parent was born in Canada pretty much tells us that he is a Canadian citizen. In any case, he needs a certificate before applying for a Canadian passport, because that's what Canada's passport application requriements [require](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/new-adult-passport/citizenship-proof.html).

Comment: @user102008 apparently, "already recognized as a citizen" means that Canada has enough information not to approve an ETA. I suppose there is a different standard of evidence for refusing ETA than for issuing a passport (or citizenship certificate), but it all strikes me as a bit odd. An alternative course of action would be to renounce the Canadian citizenship and then apply for ETA, but the effect of being a Canadian born outside of Canada is that the cost of going to Canada is at least $100 greater than it is for a noncitizen, and that seems somewhat perverse.